# How to enable and disable context menu items on specific tree nodes using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a tree node in my WinForm application. It looks like this:

```
- Root Node 1
    - Subnode 1
    - Subnode 2
    - Subnode 3
    - Subnode 4
- Root Node 2
    - Subnode 5
    - Subnode 6
```

And I got a context menu with three items: "Edit", "Delete" and "Hide". Now I want that "Hide" is enabled for Subnode 2, Subnode 3 and Subnode 5 for example. Is this possible in C#?

I know I can disable items like this:

```
menuItem1.Enabled = false;
```

Suggestions appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your AfterSelect event for the treeview just check to see if your selected node equals your desired subnodes. If so then disable your menu item.

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Name.Equals("Node1"))
        {
            DisableHide(true);
        }
        else
        {
            DisableHide(false);
        }
    }

    private void DisableHide(bool state)
    {
        menuItem1.Enabled = state;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats what I searched for